# Django project can't connect with Postgresql database - Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x

I am using Docker with my Django project. When I am trying to run server `docker-compose up` I get error:

```
django_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
django_1  |     Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
django_1  |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It seems to me that I was trying everything. I have no idea what is wrong. My settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

I was trying also with such settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Then I get:

```
django_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I am using postgres app and I start server. There is information that server is running. It seems to me that it should be ok.
My pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I have changed my `docker-compose.yaml` and it seems working, but I have new problem. When I do simple GET request I get:

```
ProgrammingError at /data
relation "authtoken_token" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "authtoken...
```

When I was working with mysql database everything worked fine.

Comment: Well, *is* it running on that host and accepting those connections?

Comment: 1. Do you have Postgres server running? 2. What's 'db' host? Do you have its IP address defined in DNS or hosts file?

Comment: How can I check it? I updated first post.

Comment: Ummmm.... so yourrunning django as dockercontainer ... if so then you have to config to the docker container ip... notlocal

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh also!would you be kindto share your dcokers compose.yml... as well run "docker inspect yourContainerName | grep '"IPAddress"' | head -n 1" to obtained the mentioned ip

Comment: I have changed my `docker-compose.yaml` and it seems working, but I have new problem described in updated post.

Comment: @Wahtdbogh ! ALSO... on this sever, if you havent set ufw please install by (platform dependency,so google up how to...>>>>>>>> or do a "netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148257/discussion-between-scriptso-and-wahtdbogh).